# html: How to center a text in a textbox which is not centered

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to center the text in a box and this box is positioned "absolutely", not in the center. I have 2 nav boxes, one on the left, one on the right of my page.This is what I've done but it doesn't work, could you help ? :)

```
<nav id="navleft">
  <ul>              
    <li><a href="#">Qui sommes nous ?</li></a>  
    <li><a href="#">Competences</li></a>

  </ul>             


</nav>

<nav id="navright">
  <ul>

    <li><a href="#">Zone d'intervention</li></a> 
    <li><a href="#">Contact</li></a> 

  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Style** :

```
#navleft
{

text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
right: 60%;
}


#navright
{
position: absolute;
top: 70px;
left: 60%;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Apart from mixing up `</li>` and `</a>`, this looks good. What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text is already centered but `ul` have default margin , padding remove it

```
#navright ul , #navleft ul{margin:0px;padding:0px}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/L0mo7vrj/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `width` to your box and set your `ul` `padding` to `0`:
(in french: Tu doit ajouter une `width` a tes boites et mettre le `padding` de tes `ul` a `0`)

For example with `200px` `width` (in french: Par example avec une `width` de `200px`):

```
#navleft {
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 70px;
  width: 200px;
}
#navright {
  border: 1px solid black;
  left: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 70px;
  width: 200px;
}
#navleft ul,#navright ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/xh4537bo/